# Javascript: Validating dynamically created radio button list control in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, radio-button

I have an ASPX page where in the page load i am dynamically creating some radio button list controls and rendering to browser.I will have 2 list items in each radio button list .One is Yes and second is No. The number of Radio buttonlist can be n.Now in my java script code, i want to know which radio button is clicked . I m already using jQuery .any easy way to handle this ?

My HTML rendered to browser is

```
<table border="0" id="tblQuestions">
    <tr>
        <td>Do you have a valid passport ?</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><table id="answer-1" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="answer-1_0" type="radio" name="answer-1" value="1" /><label for="answer-1_0">Yes</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="answer-1_1" type="radio" name="answer-1" value="0" /><label for="answer-1_1">No</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td>Are you married ?</td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td><table id="answer-2" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><input id="answer-2_0" type="radio" name="answer-2" value="1" /><label for="answer-2_0">Yes</label></td>
            </tr><tr>
                <td><input id="answer-2_1" type="radio" name="answer-2" value="0" /><label for="answer-2_1">No</label></td>
            </tr>
        </table></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code doesn't specifically answer your question, but it might help.  I'd modify it for you, but I just don't have the time right now.

I use this on exams, to warn the user that a particular question doesn't have a selected answer.

The questions are generated dynamically using a Server control which emits plain xhtml.  I name all options with the same name, (Q1, Q2...), and ID them like (Q1a, Q1b ...)

To modify it for your purposes, perhaps you could build a list of selected options in the j loop, that is, adding name -value pairs where the "break" statement is.

```
// Grabs all inputs - radio, checkbox, text, buttons and lists -sticks them in an array
allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var last = "NameUnlikelyToBeUsedAsAnElementName";

// walk through the array
for (i = 0; i< allInputs.length; i++)
{
    var input = allInputs[i];
    if (input.name == last) continue; // if this object name is the same as the last checked radio, go to next iteration


    // checks to see if any  one of  similarly named radiobuttons is checked 
    else if (input.type == "radio" )
    {    
        last = input.name;  
        var radios = document.getElementsByName(input.name);
        var radioSelected=false;

         //iterate over question options
        for (j=0; j < radios.length; j++)
        {
            if(radios[j].checked)
            {
               radioSelected=true;
               break; // Found it, proceed to next question 
            }
        }
        if (!radioSelected) // no option selected
        {       // warn user, focus question
            alert("You did not answer question " + input.id.substring(0,input.id.length-1));
            input.focus();
            return false;
        }                   
    }

}

return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is with the assumption that you already have jquery included in your page.

define a class on your radio button items, basically your client side HTML should look like `<input id="answer-2_1" type="radio" name="answer-2" value="0" class="myrdo" />`

now, in your js code, simply wire up an event handler on the class

```
$(".myrdo").bind("click",function(){if($(this).attr("checked")==true) {alert($(this).val);} });
```

the above command will simply alert the value of the selected radio button.