# Validate radio button is chosen

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, radio-button

I've been searching and trying so many different ways to get this form validate on submit working for radio buttons with no luck.

I have a form named

```
user_details
```

I have several radio groups, one is

```
overall_experience
```

another one is

```
promptness
```

How in the world can I get my simple javascript function validateForm to make sure an end user has selected one of the radio buttons in each group?

I have this (see screen shot here)
[image: http://michaeljbaran.com/script.png]

but the radio check code is not right.

Does anyone have any idea how I can make sure that an end user has selected at least one option from each radio group?

Comment: please include code in the question. and you can include pictures in the post rather than links to pictures.

Comment: you should include the code that calls the `validateForm` function as well please

Comment: the validateForm function is in the screen grab.  The forum was giving me a problem with adding code and images within my post.  Sorry.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["user_details"]["Name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter your name");
  return false;
  }
  
  //a variable that will hold the index number of the selected radio button
for (i=0;i<document.user_details.overall_experience.length;i++){
if (document.user_details.overall_experience[i].checked==true)
theone=i
else
alert("Please rate every question.");
 return false;
}
}
</script>

Comment: you can see the form here - http://michaeljbaran.com/form.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/915205/javascript-validating-dynamically-created-radio-button-list-control-in-asp-net/915687#915687

Answer (score 1):

have a look at this hope this is what you need: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fQTUp/272/)

```
<table width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="1" class="a" />1</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="2" class="a" />2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="3" class="a" />3</td>
        <td>
            <input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="4" class="a" />4</td>
        <td>
            <input name="overall_experience" type="radio" value="5" class="a" />5</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>
</div>
<div style="width:100%;clear:both;">
    <div class="fullwidth_question"> <span>2. The promptness...they got there when they said they would.</span> 
    </div>
    <div class="fullwidth_answer_indented">
        <table width="440" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="promptness" value="1" class="b" />1</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="promptness" value="2" class="b" />2</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="promptness" value="3" class="b" />3</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="promptness" value="4" class="b" />4</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="promptness" value="5" class="b" />5</td>
            </tr>
            <input type="button" value="butt" id="butt">
```

and relevant jquery is:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">  </script>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function validater() {
    $("#butt").click(function (event) {
        if($(".a").is(':checked') && $(".b").is(':checked') ){
           alert("ok");
            return true;}
        else{alert("nok");
      return false;}
    });
 });
 </script>
```

And call validater() on onSubmit of your form.

Comment: that didn't work - I used this
 if(document.getElementByClassName('overall_experience').checked) {
  return true;
}
else{
 return false;
}

Comment: but it let me submit the form without checking a radio button for overall_experience

Comment: go here and view source - I hope someone can help.  I know I have to be doing something wrong that's so easy to correct http://michaeljbaran.com/formNew.html

Comment: add class to your radio buttons, you have not added any class to your radio buttons in "michaeljbaran.com/formNew.html"

Comment: you're not talking about a css class I take it - can you please explain what exactly I need to change in this code
<input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="1" />

1

<input type="radio" name="overall_experience" value="2" />

2

Comment: is it just add class="check" so it'd be <input type="radio" class="check" name="overall_experience" value="1">

Comment: and I'd like the end user to get alerted - so would the script be
if(document.getElementByClassName('check').checked) {
  return true;
}
else{
 alert("Please rate Question 1");
 return false;
}

Comment: please do remember to mark this as correct answer if that serves your purpose :)

Comment: I don't want the end user to get an alert that it's ok if it's checked.  They're only to get an alert when it's not checked.  And it'd be more helpful if you took my form here http://michaeljbaran.com/formNew.html and altered the script if at all possible - if not I may be able to understand what it is that I'm supposed to do in order to get it working.

Comment: I'd need it to go into my function validateForm() section - and yes - you can see it here http://michaeljbaran.com/formNew2.html  I changed your #butt reference to Enter because that's what my button is named

Comment: name of your button is "s1" and its value is "Enter" in the link you provided.. so that wont work, and besides that you should be giving id of the button not name in place of "butt".

Comment: and why the hell are you using.... var x=document.forms["user_details"]["Name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Please enter your name");
  return false;
  }.....   just use "<input name="Name" type="text" id="Name" size="15" required/>" instead..

Comment: and dont just copy paste the jquery code from jsfiddle..

use the jquery code i have provided here in the answer.

Comment: I will try this again, right now I have a different project I'm working on.  I'll let you know if I get ti to work.  Thank you.

Comment: @fineartist: okay,you can mail me the relevant file at amitsingh9thjan@gmail.com if it still doesn't work.